# weblogic server script to deploy application programmatically

Tags: java, scripting, weblogic-10.x, wlst

Am looking for an option to deploy application(EAR/WAR/JAR) on weblogic server through script, where the script is executed through Java main class.

I have tried to achieve the same through Java like:

```
private static final String wlUsername = "'weblogic'";
private static final String wlPassword = "'welcome1'";

private static void connect() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append("connect(");
        buffer.append(wlUsername);
        buffer.append(",");
        buffer.append(wlPassword);
        buffer.append(")");
        log.debug("connect: "+buffer.toString());
        interpreter.exec(buffer.toString());
}


private static void createServers() {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        buf.append(startTransaction());
        buf.append("man1=create('msEmbedded1','Server')\n");
        buf.append("man2=create('msEmbedded2','Server')\n");
        buf.append("clus=create('clusterEmbedded','Cluster')\n");
        buf.append("man1.setListenPort(8001)\n");
        buf.append("man2.setListenPort(9001)\n");
        buf.append("man1.setCluster(clus)\n");
        buf.append("man2.setCluster(clus)\n");
        buf.append(endTransaction());
        buf.append("print ‘Script ran successfully ...’ \n");
        interpreter.exec(buf.toString());
}

private static String startTransaction() {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        buf.append("edit()\n");
        buf.append("startEdit()\n");
        return buf.toString();
}

private static String endTransaction() {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        buf.append("save()\n");
        buf.append("activate(block='true')\n");
        //buf.append("dumpStack()");
        return buf.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
        connect();
        enableMbeanServer();
        createServers();
}

private static void enableMbeanServer(){
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        buf.append(startTransaction());
        buf.append("set('CompatibilityMBeanServerEnabled', 'true')");
        buf.append(endTransaction());
        buf.append("shutdown()");
        connect();
        buf.append("print ‘CompatabilityMBeanServer enabled successfully ...’ \n");
        interpreter.exec(buf.toString());
}
```

But, end up with the below exception:

```
20:41:59.927 DEBUG [main][com.fedex.interfaces.wls.WLSTRunner] connect: connect('weblogic','welcome1')
Connecting to t3://localhost:7001 with userid weblogic ...

The CompatabilityMBeanServer is not initialized properly. 
This might happen if the CompatabilityMBeanServer is 
disabled via the JMXMBean.

To view the root cause exception use dumpStack()

WLST detected that the RuntimeMBeanServer is not enabled. This 
might happen if the RuntimeMBeanServer is disabled via the JMXMBean. 
Please ensure that this MBeanServer is enabled. Online WLST cannot 
function without this MBeanServer.
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in ?
  File "<iostream>", line 22, in connect
  File "<iostream>", line 648, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occured while performing connect : "Cannot connect to WLST." 
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace
```

Any suggestion or any idea how to invoke deploy/undeploy task from Java?

Comment: You can use ant to do this task using **wldeploy** task. And you can execute that ant task using *java* as well.

Comment: @Sanjeev any examples using ANT to start and stop the server based on conditions and deploy?

Comment: another approach is to use WLST scripts

Comment: @Rembo Please see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/programming/wldeploy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Weblogic Ant task instead of writing an application to do that. This is Weblogic Ant Task [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13706/wldeploy.htm#WLPRG436) . You can follow this [example](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=373) as well.

To restart weblogic, check the [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13706/ant_tasks.htm#WLPRG142)

```
<target name="start-server">
  <wlserver dir="./config" host="127.0.0.1" port="7001" action="start"/>
</target>
```

and  [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/84159/how-do-i-restart-a-weblogic-domain-remotely-using-ant)

Answer (score 0):

If WLS is complaining cause the RuntimeMBeanServer is not enabled, just enable it.

Assumptions:

1. WLS domain is located in
   /oracle/app/oracle/gc_inst/user_projects/domains/GCDomain
2. applies to WLS10.3.6, not tested on other versions.

Here are the steps:

1) Enable Platform MBean Server if disabled:

1.1. From WLS admin console, go to GCDomain > Configuration > General > Advanced

1.2. Select **Platform MBean Server Enabled**, save the changes and activate the changes.

1.3. Restart the admin server.

2) enable env variables for GCDomain

```
cd /oracle/app/oracle/gc_inst/user_projects/domains/GCDomain/bin
source setDomainEnv.sh
```

3) enable the RuntimeMBeanServerEnabled from WLST
    java weblogic.WLST

```
Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
Type help() for help on available commands
wls:/offline> readDomain('/oracle/app/oracle/gc_inst/user_projects/domains/GCDomain')
wls:/offline/GCDomain>cd('JMX/NO_NAME_0')
wls:/offline/GCDomain/JMX/NO_NAME_0>set('PlatformMBeanServerUsed','true')
wls:/offline/GCDomain/JMX/NO_NAME_0>set('PlatformMBeanServerEnabled','true')
wls:/offline/GCDomain/JMX/NO_NAME_0>set('RuntimeMBeanServerEnabled', 'true')
wls:/offline/GCDomain/JMX/NO_NAME_0>updateDomain()
wls:/offline/GCDomain/JMX/NO_NAME_0>closeDomain()
wls:/offline>exit()
```

Good luck with it!!